# How to test rendering a partial with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I want to test rendering a particular partial according to some conditions.

For example, in model show action view `show.html.erb` I have:

```
<% if condition1 %>
 <%=  render :partial => "partial1" %>
<% else %>
 <%=  render :partial => "partial1" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried:

```
response.should render_template("partial_name")
```

but it tells that it rendered "show" template

> expecting <"partial1"> but rendering with <"model/show,
>   layouts/application">

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/view-specs/view-spec

Comment: I need to test in controller_spec

Comment: `render_template` delegates to `assert_template` in [action_controller/test_case.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L67) so that's where the most detailed documentation lives

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Also try this

```
response.should render_template(:partial => 'partial_name')
```

Comment: It works, but you need to specify `render_views` if you're writing controller specs.

Comment: Can you expand on the render_views thing? render_template isn't working for me in controller tests.

Comment: `render_views` is simply called within the describe block.`describe OrganizationsController do; render_views; ...`

Comment: With the latest version of rpec it may look more like this `expect(response).to render_template(:partial => '_partial_name')`

Comment: Here's some documentation regarding `render_views`: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Comment: Latest rspec will pass with `expect(response).to render_partial("partial_name")` rouan's approach also works.

Comment: @c.apolzon I got undefined method 'render_partial' using today's updated rspec-rails ~> 2.14.0 and shoulda-matchers git-branch dp-rails-four. What gem are you using to get `render_partial` matcher? Thanks

Comment: For rspec `3.6.0` use `expect(response).to render_partial("_partial_name")` but you have to use `render_views` within `describe`. Mind the `_` in the name of the partial

Answer (score 34):

Latest rspec version suggest to use `expect` syntax rather than `should`:

```
expect(response).to render_template(partial: 'partial_name')
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are testing this inside a **controller** you should do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe Users::RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #new" do
    render_views

    it "render customer partial" do
      get :new
      expect(response).to render_template :new
      expect(response).to render_template(partial: '_new_customer')
    end
  end
end
```

Note that we need **render_views** as reported into [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/render-views).

And this is the line that will test if "_new_customer" partial is rendered:

```
expect(response).to render_template(partial: '_new_customer')
```

You need to provide the name of the partial with the initial underscore.

Also be careful because in your code the IF and the ELSE statements are rendering the same thing.

Comment: Should you really be testing a view in a controller spec? RSpec provides spec/views for this; or you could use feature/integration tests.

Comment: @KrisKhaira well, may you need both. In a controller spec you could test that the controller is going to render the expected template/view. Then in feature/integration tests you can deeply test the whole floe, in particular the view to test if user is able to perform expected actions.

Answer (score 1):

If using in rspec controllers

```
expect(response).to render_template(partial: 'home/_sector_performance')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also test, if your controller inferred required action.

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "model_name/new.html.erb" do
 it "infers the controller path" do
  expect(controller.request.path_parameters["action"]).to eq("new")
 end
end
```

The docs are [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/view-specs/view-spec-infers-controller-path-and-action)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Rails 5.1, [this kind of test is discouraged and you should test the controller and the view as a whole](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f42ac6a06880bfc02857ab71758214ad7867c22f).

Checking which partial is rendered by the controlled is part of the implementation details you shouldn't test.

Therefore I suggest you to write a request test and check that some relevant text of your partial is present in the response body.

```
get root_path
expect(CGI.unescape_html(response.body)).to include('Hello World')
```

Comment: why do you need need `CGI.unescape_html` ?

Comment: because if you check for a string that contains characters like `'`, it would fail otherwise

Answer (score -4):

Instead of the above mentioned solution you could check alternatively, if the html that the partial renders is present. E.g.

```
response.body.should have_tag("div#foo")
```

Comment: that would be a pretty fragile test -- such that the test would fail if you changed the html, but what you're really testing is whether or not the template gets rendered.

Comment: Spec should test test rendering partial, not html body.